# Do we ever use etale coherent sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

In my experience with algebraic geometry we are interested in either

1. Coherent sheaves with the Zariski topology (for geometry)
2. Abelian group or sets or groupoid sheaves with the etale topology (respectively useful for arithmetic geometry and moduli spaces)

How come we're not interested in etale coherent sheaves; by which I mean using the etale cohomology (Say big site) s.t on a scheme $X$, the sheaf is a $\Gamma(X)$ module (i.e similiar to the Zariski topology).

Comment: Did you mean to say "etale topology" where you wrote "Zariski topology" in the second example?

Comment: @TabesBridges Yes, fixed

Comment: First of all, you need to redefine what it means to be coherent when using something other than the Zariski topology. Secondly, if you are interested in extending coherent sheaves to etale covers, then in a sense, passing from the Zariski topology to the etale topology doesn't give you new information. At least the cohomology of a quasi-coherent sheaf doesn't change: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DW.

Comment: And also, the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on something like a Deligne-Mumford stack is something I would personally consider a version of a category of etale (quasi-)coherent sheaves.

Comment: @IDC thanks those are good answers. I also found that zariski and etale bundles are the same. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studying coherent sheaves on the small étale site of a scheme $S$ is not tremendously interesting: according to [Proposition 35.8.9 [03DX]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DX) of The Stacks Project, there is a natural functor which gives an equivalence of categories between the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $S$ and the category of quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}$-modules on the small étale site of $S$.

On the other hand, once you go deeper down the rabbit hole and start considering sheaves on stacks, the étale site reappears. For example, one can define quasi-coherent sheaves on a Deligne-Mumford stack by descending quasi coherent sheaves from its étale presentation by a scheme.